# Leaflet - how to get work overlay layer crs with base layer crs

Tags: leaflet, projection

Using Leaflet v1.2.0.
I have a map base tile layer with crs EPSG3395 (OSM) and when I add to map an overlay tile layer with different crs (EPSG3857) I have coordinates offset.

How can I eliminate that offset?

There is an example (http://jsfiddle.net/alekzonder/qxdxqsm3/) with leaflet v1.0.0 that works perfect, but with new leaflet v1.2.0 it doesn't work.
There is a code like this:

```
  // custom 
  // calculate crs level for custom crs
  // 
  level.__customCrsLevel = {};

  var a = map._getNewPixelOrigin(
    map.getCenter(),
    undefined,
    this.options.crs
  );

  var b = map.unproject(
    a,
    undefined,
    this.options.crs
  );

  level.__customCrsLevel.origin = map.project(
    b,
    zoom,
    this.options.crs
  ).round();

  // end of custom
```

But these methods doesn't have crs parameter for now.
I spend a day to trying to modify it, but have no result.